# Apache PIG, validate input

Tags: error-handling, apache-pig

How to handle bad records in a Apache PIG scripts. In my case I'm processing a comma seperated file wich usually has 14 fields on every row.

But sometimes the row contains a \n and the record is splitted in two lines and my PIG script failes to insert this record and all records after into HBase.

The problem is that the length of the map within the UDF is always 3. Probably because of the schema defined within the PIG script. How to determine if a records has the number of fields equal to the schema...

**PIG**

```
REGISTER 'files.py' using jython as myfuncs

A = LOAD '/etl/incoming/test.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);

B = FOREACH A {
    GENERATE
    myfuncs.checkFormat(TOTUPLE(*)) as fields;
}

DUMP B;
```

**UDF**

```
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType as DataType
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.SchemaUtil as SchemaUtil

@outputSchema("record:map[]")
def checkFormat(record):
    print(type(record))
    print(record)

    record = list(record)

    print("length: %d" % len(record)) #always return 3

    return record
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write validations as Pig UDFs in [a variety of languages](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/udf.html)

I usually return the same schema with an additional field that signify validity and then Filter the results (once for logging into an error log and once for the continued operation)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to send a complete record to an UDF or do I have to send every field as a seperate argument?

Comment: You can send all the record with * as a parameter: FOREACH A GENERATE myUDF(*);

Comment: Change the schema of A to have all 14 fields- do the projection to the 3 fields you need only after validation